# php ffmpeg flv conversion error

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am trying to convert mp4 file to flv but i am getting 0 size flv files,

can you please help me out on this

```
array(45) { [0]=string(72) "FFmpeg version SVN-r26402, Copyright (c)
2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers" [1]=string(74) " built on Jan 12
2012 16:07:49 with gcc 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)" [2]=>
string(98) " configuration: --enable-libmp3lame --enable-gpl
--enable-libvorbis --disable-mmx --enable-shared" [3]=string(35) " libavutil 50.36. 0 / 50.36. 0" [4]=string(35) " libavcore 0.16. 1 /
0.16. 1" [5]=string(37) " libavcodec 52.108. 0 / 52.108. 0" [6]=string(35) " libavformat 52.93. 0 / 52.93. 0" [7]=string(35) "
libavdevice 52. 2. 3 / 52. 2. 3" [8]=string(35) " libavfilter 1.74.
0 / 1.74. 0" [9]=string(35) " libswscale 0.12. 0 / 0.12. 0" [10]=>
string(0) "" [11]=string(101) "Seems stream 0 codec frame rate
differs from container frame rate: 30000.00 (30000/1) -15.00 (15/1)"
[12]=string(106) "Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from
'16112007069.mp4':"
[13]=string(11) " Metadata:" [14]=string(26) " major_brand : mp42"
[15]=string(23) " minor_version : 0" [16]=string(35) "
compatible_brands: mp423gp4isom" [17]=string(41) " creation_time :
2007-11-16 15:44:57" [18]=string(59) " Duration: 00:00:32.64, start:
0.000000, bitrate: 562 kb/s" [19]=string(115) " Stream #0.0(und): Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 352x288 [PAR 1:1 DAR 11:9], 512 kb/s, 15 fps,
15 tbr, 30k tbn, 30k tbc" [20]=string(13) " Metadata:" [21]=>
string(43) " creation_time : 2007-11-16 15:44:57" [22]=string(62) "
Stream #0.1(und): Audio: aac, 16000 Hz, mono, s16, 48 kb/s" [23]=>
string(13) " Metadata:" [24]=string(43) " creation_time : 2007-11-16
15:44:58" [25]=string(87) "WARNING: The bitrate parameter is set too
low. It takes bits/s as argument, not kbits/s" [26]=string(47)
"[buffer @ 0x94a9de0] w:352 h:288 pixfmt:yuv420p" [27]=string(98)
"[libmp3lame @ 0x94a9560] flv does not support that sample rate,
choose from (44100, 22050, 11025)." [28]=string(85) "Output #0, flv,
to '16112007069.flv':" [29]=string(11) " Metadata:" [30]=string(26) " major_brand : mp42"
[31]=string(23) " minor_version : 0" [32]=string(35) "
compatible_brands: mp423gp4isom" [33]=string(41) " creation_time :
2007-11-16 15:44:57" [34]=string(33) " encoder : Lavf52.93.0" [35]=>
string(103) " Stream #0.0(und): Video: flv, yuv420p, 352x288 [PAR 1:1
DAR 11:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 1k tbn, 15 tbc" [36]=string(13) "
Metadata:" [37]=string(43) " creation_time : 2007-11-16 15:44:57"
[38]=string(68) " Stream #0.1(und): Audio: libmp3lame, 16000 Hz,
mono, s16, 0 kb/s" [39]=string(13) " Metadata:" [40]=string(43) "
creation_time : 2007-11-16 15:44:58" [41]=string(15) "Stream
mapping:" [42]=string(21) " Stream #0.0 -#0.0" [43]=string(21) "
Stream #0.1 -#0.1" [44]=string(72) "Could not write header for
output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?)" }  




ffmpeg: /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg file




path: 16112007069.mp4




srcAR: 16000




srcAB:48




dimention: 352 x 288 destFile: 16112007069.flv
```

coding part: :)

```
$srcFile = "/file destination/16112007069.mp4";  
$destFile = "/file destination/16112007069.flv"; 
$ffmpegPath = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg"; 

$ffmpegObj = new ffmpeg_movie($srcFile); 

$srcWidth = makeMultipleTwo($ffmpegObj->getFrameWidth());  
$srcHeight = makeMultipleTwo($ffmpegObj->getFrameHeight());
$srcFPS = $ffmpegObj->getFrameRate();  
$srcAB = intval($ffmpegObj->getAudioBitRate());   
$srcAR => $ffmpegObj->getAudioSampleRate();  

exec($ffmpegPath . " -i " . $srcFile . " -ar " . $srcAR . " -ab " . $srcAB . " -f flv -s " . $srcWidth . "x" . $srcHeight . " " . $destFile . " 2>&1", $output); 

var_dump($output);

print "<br />ffmpeg: $ffmpegPath<br />"; print "file path: $srcFile<br
/>"; print "srcAR: $srcAR<br />"; print "srcAB: $srcAB<br />"; print
"dimention: $srcWidth x $srcHeight<br />"; print "destFile:
$destFile<br />";


function makeMultipleTwo ($value)  { 
    $sType = gettype($value/2); 
    if($sType == "integer") 
    { 
        return $value; 
    } else { 
        return ($value-1); 
    }  
}
```

**Note** I added:

```
if($srcAR<41000){ $srcAR = "41000"; }
```

Above and its working!

Comment: Where is the programming part of this question?

Comment: "WARNING: The bitrate parameter is set too low. It takes bits/s as argument, not kbits/s"  ?

Comment: so what should i do to get it right, i have posted the code

Comment: ok i have editted the bitrate problem, but still there are additional errors,

Comment: just added if($srcAR<41000){ $srcAR = "41000"; } every thing working fine :)

Comment: Please post new Answer with what you have done to solve this and mark as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

test this one :

```
ffmpeg -i src.avi -an dest.flv
```

Answer (score 0):

try this $ffmpeg -i src.avi dest.flv